# How to parameterize environment variables from within package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following hardcoded variable in my **package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
   "generate:test": USER_CODE=1839 node generateNewUsers"
}
```

I can then access this in **generateNewUsers.js** like so:

```
userCode = `${process.env.USER_CODE}`;
```

How do I parameterize the value in the package.json such that I can pass in different values at runtime, say from a groovy pipeline?

**pipeline.groovy**

```
  stage('Running API Tests') {
        sh "npm run generate:test${params.USER_CODE}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "parameterize a package.json" file because it never executes.
Instead, you can modify your `generate:test` script like so:

```
"scripts": {
   "generate:test": node generateNewUsers"
}
```

Now when running the script, simply run it as:

```
USER_CODE=whatever_you_want npm run generate:test
```

Comment: thanks. I think that makes sense, but didn't work when I tried it - the value was not passed.  When I run with the hardcoded value in the package.json, then it works.  But this is no good as it is hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as environment variable and add it in generateNewUsers file/ whichever will be running as first file!

```
const USER_CODE = process.env.USER_CODE
```

then pass in command line

Comment: thanks; as per question, I am, already using it in the JS file with process.env.USER_CODE.  I need to know the syntax that allows me to pass from a Groovy pipeline as per amended question.  When I tried USER_CODE=whatever_you_want npm run generate:test as suggested below, this did not work